# fading content in a carousel with angular

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and am trying to figure it out, though I'm now stuck on animating content inside a content based carousel. I've built this carousel myself, but I didn't consider how fading content between "slides" would play into this beforehand.

Currently the structure of my carousel is:

```
<article class="container-fluid carousel-container" ng-controller="carouselController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="prev-container">
            <button class="prev" ng-click="prevSlide()"><span>&lsaquo;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="slide-left">
                <h1 class="slide-inner" ng-cloak>{{panels[slide].title}}</h1>
                <p class="slide-inner" ng-cloak>{{panels[slide].body}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="next-container">
            <button class="next" ng-click="nextSlide()"><span>&rsaquo;</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Instead of having actual slides, I am simply changing the content of a single 'slide'. Later on I'll be adding images in a `slide-right` container.

The functionality for this resides in the `carouselController`:

```
app.controller('carouselController', function($scope){
    $scope.slide = 0;
    $scope.prevSlide = function(){
        if ($scope.slide <= 0) {
            $scope.slide = ($scope.panels.length - 1);
        } else {
            $scope.slide--;
        };
    };
    $scope.nextSlide = function(){
        if ($scope.slide >= $scope.panels.length - 1) {
            $scope.slide = 0;
        } else {
            $scope.slide++;
        };
    };
    $scope.panels = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "1 - Lorem ipsum",
            body: "1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, dolores voluptas quod fuga id nihil in! Dolore accusantium perferendis deleniti voluptate, libero quis at molestias."

        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "2 - Lorem ipsum",
            body: "2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, dolores voluptas quod fuga id nihil in! Dolore accusantium perferendis deleniti voluptate, libero quis at molestias."
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "3 - Lorem ipsum",
            body: "3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, dolores voluptas quod fuga id nihil in! Dolore accusantium perferendis deleniti voluptate, libero quis at molestias."
        }
    ];
});
```

The basic idea here is that the content is populated from the `panels` array, and clicking the next button or prev button will increment or decrement the array index, respectively. This then populates the title and body content inside the `slide-left` div. The issue I am having is when the next or prev button is used, i want to fade out the content that is there, and fade in new content. I have tried `addClass` and `removeClass`, and many other methods with no results. The biggest roadblock has been the fact that I am not actually changing slides and just content as most resources and tutorials assume I am hiding one slide, and revealing the next. I look forward to your suggestions and appreciate your help, and feel free to criticize my existing code.

Comment: Consider using ng-repeat to render panels of all slides, and ng-show to show the active slide. Then your animation should be possible.

Comment: @ShaunScovil is it not possible this way? I have considered that, but prefer to solve the problem rather than work around it.

Comment: I wouldn't call one a workaround. The question is, do you expect some sort of cross-fading animation, or do you just want to move your slide out, then change its content and move it back in?

Comment: This slide example will probably answer your question better than I can: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#javascript-based-animations

Comment: I just want to fade the content out and fade the new content in. Ideally I'll be able to do any css3 animation, transitions, etc. I looked towards `ng-animate` but the issue is it depends on temporary classes from what I see, and as this isn't using `ng-repeat` it doesn't have temporary classes, is there a way to create them and the behavior around it?

Comment: The carousel on this site is a good example of both the layout and effects I will eventually create https://auth0.com. I really don't want to avoid the issue, but if I'm going about this completely the wrong way then I don't mind changing it. I just thought it would be unnecessary to use `ng-repeat` if i dont actually want to repeat the container and just want to change the content. I'll trust the advice of someone who has more experience with angular than i do lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build a carousel with a fade in/out transition and avoid using [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate), here is one approach that involves creating a set of custom directives.

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/pnz1fh10/)

### Template

Here is what the HTML would look like using this method:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
  <carousel panels="vm.panels">
    <carousel-panel>
      <h1>{{$title}}</h1>
      <p>{{$body}}</p>
    </carousel-panel>
    <button carousel-prev>
      &lsaquo; Prev
    </button>
    <button carousel-next>
      Next &rsaquo;
    </button>
  </carousel>
</div>
```

Notice there are four (4) directives used:

1. carousel
2. carousel-panel
3. carousel-next
4. carousel-prev

The first one, `carousel`, is a wrapper that is required to be the parent element of the others. This enables each child component to interact with `carousel`'s controller, while clearly separating the concerns of each and not creating any hidden dependencies.

### Carousel

This directive has a controller that exposes data and functionality to the child directives that require it. It has a `panels` property, which is a two-way-binding from its `panels` attribute. It also has a `slide` property to keep track of which panel is visible; and `next()` and `prev()` functions for adjusting that value.

```
angular.module('myApp.carousel')
  .controller('CarouselController', CarouselController)
  .directive('carousel', carouselDirective)
;

function CarouselController() {
  var carousel = this;
  carousel.slide = 0;
  carousel.current = function() {
    if (carousel.panels && carousel.panels.length) {
      return carousel.panels[carousel.slide];
    }
  };
  carousel.next = function() {
    if (carousel.panels && carousel.panels.length) {
      if (carousel.slide >= carousel.panels.length - 1) {
        carousel.slide = 0;
      } else {
        carousel.slide++;
      }
    }
  };
  carousel.prev = function() {
    if (carousel.panels && carousel.panels.length) {
      if (carousel.slide <= 0) {
        carousel.slide = carousel.panels.length - 1;
      } else {
        carousel.slide--;
      }
    }
  };
}

function carouselDirective() {
  return {
    bindToController: {
      panels: '='
    },
    controller: 'CarouselController',
    controllerAs: 'carousel',
    scope: true,
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
    transclude: true
  };
}
```

### Carousel Panel

This directive watches the `slide` property of its parent `CarouselController` and adds a `.fade` class to itself whenever that value changes. It then sets a timeout (hard-coded at 500ms in this example) and removes the `.fade` class when the delay has passed. This is designed to work with a pure CSS transition, discussed below.

```
angular.module('myApp.carousel')
  .directive('carouselPanel', carouselPanelDirective)
;

function carouselPanelDirective($timeout) {
  return {
    link: postLink,
    require: '^carousel',
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
    transclude: true
  };

  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, carousel) {
    scope.$watch(currentSlide, transition);

    function currentSlide() {
      return carousel.slide;
    }

    function fadeOut() {
      iElement.addClass('fade');
    }

    function fadeIn() {
      iElement.removeClass('fade');      
    }

    function refresh() {
      var current = carousel.current();
      scope.$title = current.title;
      scope.$body = current.body;
    }

    function transition(currentSlide, previousSlide) {
      if (currentSlide === previousSlide) {
        refresh();
      } else {
        fadeOut();
        $timeout(function() {
          refresh();
          fadeIn();
        }, 500);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Carousel Next & Prev

These two directives can be added as attributes to a button or any other element. They add 'click' event handlers to the element that call the `next()` and `prev()` functions of the parent `CarouselController`, respectively.

```
angular.module('myApp.carousel')
  .directive('carouselNext', carouselNextDirective)
  .directive('carouselPrev', carouselPrevDirective)
;

function carouselNextDirective() {
  return {
    link: postLink,
    require: '^carousel'
  };

  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, carousel) {
    iElement.on('click', onClick);
    scope.$on('$destroy', offClick);

    function onClick() {
      carousel.next();
      scope.$apply();
    }

    function offClick() {
      iElement.off('click', onClick);
    }
  }
}

function carouselPrevDirective() {
  return {
    link: postLink,
    require: '^carousel'
  };

  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, carousel) {
    iElement.on('click', onClick);
    scope.$on('$destroy', offClick);

    function onClick() {
      carousel.prev();
      scope.$apply();
    }

    function offClick() {
      iElement.off('click', onClick);
    }
  }
}
```

### CSS

These CSS rules target the transcluded HTML contents of `carousel-panel` and apply a CSS transition using `opacity`. Note the 0.5s (or 500ms) transition time, which corresponds with the delay in our panel's `$timeout` function.

```
carousel-panel > ng-transclude > * {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

carousel-panel.fade > ng-transclude > * {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

### Conclusion

This may seem like a lot of work, but it is much more reusable, scalable and maintainable than just building the logic into a single controller. By using [transclusion](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html), you enable the application template to dictate layout (apposed to the directive template).

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is something I think I'll need to take the time to understand, I'll accept or comment after I have done that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The key piece is where I add the .fade class, then set a timeout to remove it. You could essentially just do that with your existing code, though the refresh function also plays a critical role. You need to add the .fade class; wait for that transition to finish; then change the title and body values displayed in your template, and remove the .fade class.

Comment: @NathanLykke here is an example using your existing code: https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/j8ksg9ur/ -- this uses `$element` to perform DOM manipulation in the controller, which goes against Angular best practices, but hopefully it will help you draw parallels between your existing code and my recommended changes.

Comment: thank you, the functionality in the js fiddle is exactly what I am looking to do, though I absolutely would like to learn best practices so I will be working with your suggestion, I will let you know if it works out or if I have complications. Thank you so much for your help with this.

Comment: This absolutely worked, however I realize that i understand about 10% of it, I'll have a lot of research to do to understand it fully. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out. Learn about the digest cycle and how/why it gets triggered, and a lot of this should make sense.